24.04 LTS Samba Share Windows 11 Mount Working - Windows 10 Fails
I have a samba share folder on a 24.04 LTS server configured to allow direct access to a 'Public' folder mounted at boot via /etc/fstab configuration.
On two Windows 11 PC's, I can simply browse in Explorer to \ of server and immediately see the shared folder.  Similarly, if I run "net use P: \<shared folder>" the mount is created immediately and works as expected.
On a Windows 10 PC in the same local network when I try to access the samba folder in Explorer, mount via 'net use', etc., I am prompted for a user name and password. Yet no combination of credentials works (hitting 'other' to enter server name\user, different accounts, etc.).  The 'net use' command echoes that the password is invalid.
Note that from this Windows 10 PC I am able to sftp into the same ubuntu server with the credentials I'm using trying to mount the samba share.
Is there some difference between Win11 and Win10 that I'm missing?  Why would only the Win10 machine prompt for a user/password when Win11 does not?  All Windows PC's have network discovery turned on, and are using 'Private' network settings.
Could I have a setting in fstab or smb.conf that is causing this behavior?
Here is the mount line from my fstab file:
UUID="5B2C219C5E6CBAEC" /home/public/Public ntfs-3g auto,user,exec,uid=1002,gid=1002,dmask=000,fmask=111,utf8 0 0

And the output from testparm -s:
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
Loaded services file OK.
Weak crypto is allowed by GnuTLS (e.g. NTLM as a compatibility fallback)

Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

# Global parameters
[global]
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    logging = file
    map to guest = Bad User
    max log size = 1000
    obey pam restrictions = Yes
    pam password change = Yes
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    server role = standalone server
    server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
    unix password sync = Yes
    usershare allow guests = Yes
    workgroup = WAYCLAN
    idmap config * : backend = tdb

[printers]
    browseable = No
    comment = All Printers
    create mask = 0700
    path = /var/tmp
    printable = Yes

[print$]
    comment = Printer Drivers
    path = /var/lib/samba/printers

[Public]
    comment = Samba on Ubuntu
    guest ok = Yes
    guest only = Yes
    path = /home/public/Public
    read only = No


What would help is to edit your original post and add the output of testparm -s and the line in fstab you use to mount to the Public folder.

Added the fstab and testparm information to the original question, sorry the formatting is a bit wonky.

Is the "public" in /home/public a user name?

Enable samba log and see if there is an permission error. I guess you are using the wrong username. samba users differ from linux users.

Thank you both for the replies - I'd somehow missed that samba users were unique from my linux users!  Rookie mistake, now I can at least determine a path forward.

You have a guest accessible share. You shouldn't need to pass any user name or password.
Note: To be honest I'm trying to figure out how your Win11 machines are able to access this share.
You never answered my question so I'm going to assume "public" ( lower case p in the /home/public path ) is a user name:
[1] /home/public prevents everyone other than the user public from getting to anything under that folder.
It's not a samba thing it's a Linux thing. One way around this problem is to allow users other than "public" to get to the Public folder by running:
chmod o+x /home/public

[2] Then there is the guest only = Yes parameter.
That does pretty much what you would think it does and allows only guest access to the share. If you ever added a windows user to the samba password database that user would not be able to access the share.
I would remove that option from the share definition in smb.conf and restart smbd:
sudo service smbd restart

There is a third possible issue and one I've never had myself and that is that some Windows installations don't allow guest access to other systems shares. I don't like giving instructions on changing the internal plumbing of Windows machines so I would suggest you refer to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/enable-insecure-guest-logons-smb2-and-smb3?tabs=group-policy

Thanks again @Morbius1, your feedback was very helpful - indeed I didn't answer your question about 'public'.  That is a linux user, and I mounted the 'Public' partition there as my samba share.  Removing the guest only in smb.conf also made sense, and led me to trying the simple guest/ from the Windows machine and this worked.  I appreciate your time adding feedback to my question!
